# Why doesn't this execute properly? And why doesn't it take value for rpm from the user?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() {

    float x;
    printf("Temperature = %f", x);
    scanf("%f \n", &x);

    int y;
    printf("Sensor Reading = %d ", y);
    scanf("%d \n", &y);

    int z;
    printf("RPM Value = %d", z);
    scanf("%d", &z);
    if((x<=143.4)&&(y=0)) {
        printf("Continue to run\n");
        printf("Temperature is Low\n");
        printf("Not mixed correctly\n");
        if(z<400) {
            printf("Increase the speed to 400rpm");
        } else if(z>400) {
            printf("Decrease the speed to 400rpm");
        } else {
            printf("keep running at this speed");
        }
    } else {
        printf("stop running\n");
        printf("Temperature is above 143.4 degree Celcius\n");
        printf("Colors are mixed correctly\n");
    }
}
```

This is my code for the question given below whats wrong in this?

A chemical mixture is running at a fabric coloring plant. If the mixture's temperature rises above 143.4◦C the mixing should be stopped. There is a sensor inside the mixture to check whether the colors are mixed to the expected color, if the color is correct the sensor will send a signal `1`, otherwise `0`. If the colors are mixed correctly, you need the mixture to stop mixing. If the mixtures motor should be running at speed of 400rpm, if the speed is lower you must increase the speed or otherwise decrease speed. Write a program to print the status of the mixture(whether continuing to run, stopping, increasing/decreasing speed) with details such as reasons to stop. Accept user inputs as the temperature, sensor reading and RPM value and check diﬀerent inputs.

Comment: did you mean `y==0`?

Comment: Where did you get the idea of such a formatting?

Comment: You're printing the values before reading them.

Comment: printf and scanf are wrong... And why "y==0"? I can't find the reason in the instructions

Comment: y=0 is the output by the sensor

Comment: `void main()` is not following any standard

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not running properly is you are printing value before assigning value to a variable and in if condition you assigning value to y(by doing y=0) instead of comparing value(like this y==0).

Try the below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() {

    float x;
    printf("Enter Temperature: ");
    scanf("%f", &x);


    int y;
    printf("Enter Sensor Reading: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);


    int z;
    printf("Enter RPM Value: ");
    scanf("%d", &z);
    printf("\nTemperature = %f\n", x);
    printf("Sensor Reading = %d\n", y);
    printf("RPM Value = %d\n\n", z);

    if( x <= 143.4 && y == 0 ) 
    {
        printf("Continue to run\n");
        printf("Temperature is Low\n");
        printf("Not mixed correctly\n");
        if( z < 400 ) 
        {
            printf("Increase the speed to 400rpm\n");
        } 
        else if( z > 400 ) 
        {
            printf("Decrease the speed to 400rpm\n");
        } 
        else 
        {
            printf("keep running at this speed\n");
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        printf("stop running\n");
        if( x > 143.4 )
        {
            printf("Temperature is above 143.4 degree Celcius\n");
        }
        if( y == 1 )
        {
            printf("Colors are mixed correctly\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense to ask for data before printing them.

This is setting `y` to `0`:    `y=0`
   This is checking of `y` is equal `0`: `y==0`

Take a look at:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void main(void) {

    float x;

    printf("Set Temperature:\n"); 

    scanf("%f", &x);
    printf("Temperature = %.3f\n", x);


    int y;

    printf("Set Sensor Reading:\n"); 
    scanf("%d", &y);    
    printf("Sensor Reading = %d \n", y);


    int z;

    printf("Set RPM Value:\n", z);
    scanf("%d", &z);
    printf("RPM Value = %d\n", z);


    if( (x<=143.4) && (y==0) ) 
    {
        printf("Continue to run\n");
        printf("Temperature is Low\n");
        printf("Not mixed correctly\n");

        if (z<400) {
            printf("Increase the speed to 400rpm\n");
        } 
        else 
            if(z>400)
            {
                printf("Decrease the speed to 400rpm\n");
            } 
            else
            {
                printf("keep running at this speed\n");
            }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("stop running\n");
        printf("Temperature is above 143.4 degree Celcius\n");
        printf("Colors are mixed correctly\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Set Temperature:                                                                                                                               
143.4                                                                                                                                          
Temperature = 143.400                                                                                                                          
Set Sensor Reading:                                                                                                                            
20                                                                                                                                             
Sensor Reading = 20                                                                                                                            
Set RPM Value:                                                                                                                                 
10                                                                                                                                             
RPM Value = 10                                                                                                                                 
stop running                                                                                                                                   
Temperature is above 143.4 degree Celcius                                                                                                      
Colors are mixed correctly
```